# Using result from aggregate in non aggregate causing issues with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, teradata, group-concat

I have one column in my query that is causing problems with my group by. If I include the column in the group I get the error: "GROUP BY and WITH...BY clauses may not contain aggregate functions." but if I remove the column from the GROUP I get " Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group."

I believe the issue to be because while the column is not aggregating itself, it is using a column that is aggregate. Please advise me if I am correct in that issue, and/or how I can fix.

```
SELECT
        //r.publicid as nNumber, 
        u.publicid as nNumber,
        d.name as department, concat(c.lastname,', ',c.firstname) AS fullName, SUBSTRING(cc2.name,1,4) as Office,
        u.jobtitle as jobTitle, 
        CASE WHEN LENGTH(cxm.lm_extension) = 5.0 THEN concat('72',cxm.lm_extension) ELSE cxm.lm_extension END AS formattedExtension,    

        //Checks how many regions are associated to user. Concatenates multiple regions      
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = '1' THEN r.regionName END)
        || MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ',' || r.regionName ELSE '' END)
        || MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ',' || r.regionName ELSE '' END)
        || MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ',' || r.regionName ELSE '' END)
        || MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN ',' || r.regionName ELSE '' END) AS region,        

        s.segmentationAttribute,       

        //Checks LOB, Department, Region and Segmentation attribute to determine the appropriate Zero out     
        CASE                 
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Third Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Northeast') THEN 'C_APD_NE_HC3_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - First Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Northeast') THEN 'C_APD_NE_HC1_COV' 
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Low Complexity' AND region = 'Northeast') THEN 'C_APD_NE_LC_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Third Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Mid-Atlantic') THEN 'C_APD_MA_HC3_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - First Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Mid-Atlantic') THEN 'C_APD_MA_HC1_COV' 
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Low Complexity' AND region = 'Mid-Atlantic') THEN 'C_APD_MA_LC_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Third Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Central') THEN 'C_APD_C_HC3_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - First Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Central') THEN 'C_APD_C_HC1_COV' 
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Low Complexity' AND region = 'Central') THEN 'C_APD_C_LC_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Third Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Southeast') THEN 'C_APD_SE_HC3_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - First Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'Southeast') THEN 'C_APD_SE_HC1_COV' 
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Low Complexity' AND region = 'Southeast') THEN 'C_APD_SE_LC_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Third Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'West') THEN 'C_APD_W_HC3_COV'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - First Party PD - High Complexity' AND region = 'West') THEN 'C_APD_W_HC1_COV' 
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'APD - Low Complexity' AND region = 'West') THEN 'C_APD_W_LC_COV'
        //Block below checks for appraisal and region
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0275') THEN 'C0275 Sk324Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0336') THEN 'C0336 Sk466 Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0980') THEN 'C0980 Sk554Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0508') THEN 'C0508 Sk680 Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0897') THEN 'C0897 Sk1052Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0647') THEN 'C0647 Sk829 Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0631') THEN 'C0631 Sk795 Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0414') THEN 'C0414_Sk594_Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND department LIKE '%Appraiser%' AND office = '0179') THEN 'C0179_SK100Cov_0Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND segmentationAttribute = 'No segmentation attribute assigned') THEN 'No segmentation attribute assigned'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%APD%' AND region LIKE '%,%') THEN 'Multiple Regions assigned'           
        //Checks for Property water mit
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND department LIKE '%WATER MITIGATION%') THEN 'C0980_Sk1107_0Out'         
        //Checks property and region
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND office = '0150') THEN 'C0150_Prop0_Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND (office = '0980' OR office = '0900')) THEN 'C0980_Prop0_Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND (office = '0508' OR office = '0520')) THEN 'C0508_Prop0_Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND office = '0203') THEN 'C0203_Prop0_Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND (office = '0631' OR office = '0633')) THEN 'C0631_Prop0_Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND office = '0414') THEN 'C0414_Prop0_Out'
        WHEN (department LIKE '%PROP%' AND office = '0467') THEN 'C0467_0_Out_Sk1249'
        //Checks for NF. NF zero outs are organized by teams, no data point to query on
        WHEN (department LIKE '%NF%' OR department LIKE '%NO FAULT%') THEN 'NF'
        //Safeco Zero outs have not been determined
        WHEN department LIKE '%Saf%' THEN 'Safeco, need updated Zero outs.'
        //BI users should not have zero outs      
        WHEN department LIKE '%BI%' THEN 'No Zero Out'
        //Catch all for users not fitting into previous categories            
        ELSE 'Does not fit in any category.' 
        END AS expectedZeroOut               
FROM               
        pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_user AS u
        JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_credential AS cr ON u.credentialid = cr.id AND cr.active=1 AND cr.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' AND u.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'        
        JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_userrole AS ur ON u.id = ur.userid AND (ur.roleid = 1 OR ur.roleid = 4) AND ur.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
        JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_contact AS c ON c.id = u.contactid AND c.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
        JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.ccx_lm_contactmethod AS cxm ON u.contactID = cxm.lm_contactid AND cxm.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' 
                AND ((LENGTH(cxm.lm_extension) = 5.0 AND (cxm.lm_extension LIKE ('7%') or cxm.lm_extension LIKE ('2%')))
                OR (LENGTH(cxm.lm_extension) = 7.0 AND (cxm.lm_extension LIKE ('727%') or cxm.lm_extension LIKE ('722%'))))
        JOIN PM_ODS_CL_CC_PRL_D.cc_contactcontact AS cc1 ON u.contactid=cc1.sourcecontactid 
                AND cc1.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' AND cc1.ODS_CDC_TRANS_TYPE NOT = 'D'        
        JOIN PM_ODS_CL_CC_PRL_D.cc_contact AS cc2 ON cc1.relatedcontactid = cc2.id AND cc2.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'         
        JOIN PM_ODS_CL_CC_PRL_D.cc_contact AS d on d.lm_departmentnumber = u.department AND d.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
        JOIN (
                SELECT

                        u.publicid AS nNumber,
                        //Returns value from segmentation attribute logic/concatenation                
                        CASE 
                        WHEN a1.description IS NULL AND a2.description IS NULL AND a3.description IS NULL THEN 'No segmentation attribute assigned'
                        WHEN a1.description IS NOT NULL AND a2.description IS NULL AND a3.description IS NULL THEN a1.description
                        WHEN a1.description IS NULL AND a2.description IS NOT NULL AND a3.description IS NULL THEN a2.description
                        WHEN a1.description IS NULL AND a2.description IS NULL AND a3.description IS NOT NULL THEN a3.description
                        WHEN a1.description IS NOT NULL AND a2.description IS NOT NULL AND a3.description IS NULL THEN concat(a1.description,', ', a2.description)
                        WHEN a1.description IS NOT NULL AND a2.description IS NULL AND a3.description IS NOT NULL THEN concat(a1.description,', ', a3.description)
                        WHEN a1.description IS NULL AND a2.description IS NOT NULL AND a3.description IS NOT NULL THEN concat(a2.description,', ', a3.description)
                        WHEN a1.description IS NOT NULL AND a2.description IS NOT NULL AND a3.description IS NOT NULL THEN concat(a1.description, a2.description, a3.description)
                        END AS segmentationAttribute  

                FROM
                        pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_user AS u
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_attributeUser AS auHC3 ON u.id = auHC3.userid 
                                AND auHC3.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' AND auHC3.attributeid='1401' AND auHC3.ODS_CDC_TRANS_TYPE != 'D'
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_attributeUser AS auHC1 ON u.id = auHC1.userid 
                                AND auHC1.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' AND auHC1.attributeid='1501' AND auHC1.ODS_CDC_TRANS_TYPE != 'D'
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_attributeUser AS auLC1 ON u.id = auLC1.userid 
                                AND auLC1.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' AND auLC1.attributeid='1301' AND auLC1.ODS_CDC_TRANS_TYPE != 'D'        
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_attribute AS a1 ON a1.id=auHC3.attributeid and a1.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_attribute AS a2 ON a2.id=auHC1.attributeid and a2.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_attribute AS a3 ON a3.id=auLC1.attributeid and a3.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
                WHERE 
                        u.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59') AS s ON s.nNumber = u.publicid
        LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                        u.publicid as nNumber, g.name as regionName,                
                        //Provides row count to concate regions
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.publicid ORDER BY regionName) AS rn
                FROM 
                        pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_user AS u        
                        JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_credential AS cr ON u.credentialid = cr.id AND cr.active=1 AND u.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' AND cr.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'              
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_groupUser AS gu on gu.userID = u.id and gu.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' and gu.groupID in ('2202','2302','2303','2304','2402') and gu.ODS_CDC_TRANS_TYPE != 'D'
                        LEFT JOIN pm_ods_cl_cc_prl_d.cc_group AS g on g.ID = gu.groupID and g.ODS_EXP_ROW_DTM = '9999-12-31 23:59:59') AS r ON u.publicid = r.nNumber

    GROUP BY u.publicid,d.name,fullName,Office,u.jobtitle,formattedExtension,
s.segmentationAttribute,expectedZeroOut
```

Comment: i see 8 columns..where is 9 in group by coming from?

Comment: For start dont use numbers on `GROUP BY` that give lot of room to error to happen, like you have 8 columns but 9 on `group by`

Comment: Generally speaking, you want `GROUP BY`s to not list more than ~5 columns.  At minimum I'd probably add another layer around the `JOIN`ed subquery (which you should absolutely name), which is doing the aggregation.

Comment: There are so many errors that I think is better you show us your db schema, some sample data and expected output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Updated to include actual code

Comment: Seems like you need to remove `expectedZeroOut` from `GROUP BY` and apply a `MAX`on it. Btw, it's strongly recommended to avoid ODBC-functions like `CONCAT` (does the `//` actually work as a comment?), because #1: new ODBC-drivers no longer support them and #2: the query will fail when you switch this support off in SQL Assistant or  try to run it using .NET/CLI/JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

By all means, don't use columns' positions for aggregation.

---

```
select      userid,department,fullname,office,title,extension

           ,  max (case rn when 1 then        region else '' end)
           || max (case rn when 2 then ',' || region else '' end)
           || max (case rn when 3 then ',' || region else '' end)
           || max (case rn when 4 then ',' || region else '' end) as location

           ,max (case when region = 'West' and DEPARTMENT = 10 then 'West_10' end)    as team

from       (select      e.*
                       ,row_number() over
                        (
                            partition by    userid,department,fullname,office,title,extension 
                            order by        regionname
                        ) as rn

            from        employee
            ) 

group by    userid,department,fullname,office,title,extension
;
```

Comment: Now I receive an error of "Cannot nest aggregate operations."

Comment: @BDMorrissette, My bad, we can't use **location** in the expression that creates **team**. Let me fix that,

Comment: @BDMorrissette, fixed, also I'm not sure about the logic if the **team** definition

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post with my actual code and unfortunately the logic within the team (actual column name is expctedZeroOut) is pretty extensive. There are over 100 different permutations so I would need something that can use location. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @BDMorrissette:  If `region` is the result of the `MAX(CASE..` it will never work, as it's a comma-delimited list and you compare it to a single value. Seems like you might use the base column `r.regionName` instead.

Comment: It typically isn't comma-delimited. The expected result is to only have one Region. I built in a a "catch-all" for when it is comma delimited (see the like '%,%'. Any time there is more than one region I would expect a different behavior. The only behavior I really care is to compare the users with a single region and a single segmentation attribute.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I realized since I only care to check for locations that aren't comma delimited I can run a check on row number. I have it working now. Thanks again!